# Why not execute script in IDE?

Tags: python, ide

Are there reasons why you should execute (python) scripts from terminal/cmd, instead of directly in an IDE? How about vice-versa?

Comment: Not every machine has a GUI - many servers are command line only.

Comment: Where (source) did you see that the script should not be executed in an IDE but only from terminal?. You can execute the python code from a IDE with the run button, or from as a .py file from the terminal. Its purely depdending on the use case. No restrictions placed.

Comment: I guess the question is incorrect. An IDE provides a terminal emulator (VSCode, and PyCharm at least) which is similar to any other terminal emulator. So, running from the IDE or some specific emulator shouldn't cause any difference. I don't know if Python IDEs provide some other way to run script, other than the small terminal emulator they provide.

Comment: You can run a Python script either way. But if your objective is just to run a script, then starting an IDE, loading the script, and hitting the `run` button seems like overkill.

Comment: @MaJoR There are actually differences  between 'real' terminals and the terminal emulators from many IDEs, we get quite a lot of questions on SO caused by problems in such emulators.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I didn't want to compare the [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) and the regular terminal emulators (like the XTerm). However, if you meant opposite (ide terms are different than regular terminal emulators), then can you lead me to some differences? I have never had any difficulty or faced any difference between the two.

Comment: An IDE is a tool for working with code that, among other things, provides a way to interpret the byte code. In a production setting, you don't need all those other things; you *just* need the interpreter.

Comment: @snakecharmerb you have an excellent point, hadn't considered this.

Comment: @Jim Todd, I've seen quite a few people write their python code in an IDE, save the .py, and then execute in terminal. I assumed there would be a reason they'd do this.